# Capturing multiple value from dropdown list generated from database

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am having problem to capture multiple value from drop-down list which is generated from database.I have to capture multiple value and that also has to be saved in database.Its only capturing the last selected value id insted of all and saving that value to database.
here is my code

```
<?php

    include("config.php");
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT Emp, ed FROM pd WHERE manemail = '$mai'");

    echo "<select name='allo' multiple style='width:163px;'>";
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        $emp=$row2['Emp'];
        $ed=$row2['ed'];
        echo "<option value='".$ed."' name='" .$ed. "' >" .$emp. " </option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add brackets "[ ]" to your select's name:

```
<select name="allo[]" multiple style='width:163px;'>
```

Then, you can have all selected values in PHP, like this:

```
// Here you iterate $_GET['allo'] to get each selected id!
$array_of_ids[] = array();
foreach($_GET['allo'] as $selectedOption)
    $array_of_ids[] = $selectedOption;

print_r($array_of_ids); // This array contains all the selected ids...
```

Comment: Hi as you said its working absolutely fine.but I am having problem to capture each individual id. its producing output like 330321162. which is the combination of 3 selected value.I have to capture each individual value.Can you please help me with this.Thanks for the concern

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please, take a look. The iteration returns all the selected ids... you just need to use then as you wish inside the `foreach` or like my example above...

Comment: Hi it works the way you said.but I cant save it in my database cause its an array .Is there any way to store id's into my database by breaking all the different id's?Can you please hel me with that? Thanks in advance!and thanks for your support!

Comment: You are not giving me enough information to help you more... Give me a piece of code showing what are you trying to do now... Or create another thread at SO with your new doubt.

Comment: Actually using those id's I have to send mail dynamically(those id's will be used to retrieve email id's from database ) So I need each and Individual number to retrieve data.Can you please help me with that.I have written perfect code to sendmail but problem is I can not make out each individual id's from above.

Comment: I guess it be better if you create a new thread at SO to your new question... I can help you there. The question you have now looks totaly diferent than the original one on this thread. Send me the link for your new question.

Comment: hey I have solve my issue!Thanks for your continuous support!